# Event Value ? Google analytics / measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

How to use event value / view it when I use event tracking with measurement protocol. Currently in events tab in google analytics UI, I can check category , action but cant see the value associated with it that I sent to GA.

Thanks

Answer (score 68):

First off, make sure you are passing a correct value to the `value` argument. The `value` argument expects an *integer* value (not string), e.g.

```
// bad
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label', "some random string"]);

// bad
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label', "123"]);

// good
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label', 123]);
```

2nd, Category, Action, and Label are *dimensions*; what you see on the left side of a given report. Value, on the other hand, is a *metric*; what you see on the *right* side of the report. This is what makes for the actual numbers you are looking at when you go to your events reports and look at category/action/label reports.  A dimension is *what* the event was. dimension values are unique values per row.  A metric is a quantifier for the dimension, e.g. how many times the event happened, or averages, etc..

For example:

```
Event Category      Total Events  Unique Events  Event Value  Avg. Value
------------------------------------------------------------------------
some category       20            8              0            0
another category    18            12             0            0
```

`value` Those last 2 columns are populated by what you specify for the `value` argument in the `_trackEvent` call.  The default value for an event is 0. So if you don't set it, all you are going to see is 0's in the **Event Value** and **Avg. Value** columns.

So let's say you have event tracking added on some links and buttons on your site. Let's say you have things wired up to trigger the following on a certain button:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links and Buttons', 'click', 'CTA', 'buy me!', 1]);
```

For simplifying **Unique Events** we'll say all 10 clicks were done by the same person. But note that **Unique Events** is a per visitor deduped `Total Events` value.

In your category report you should see something like this:

```
Event Category      Total Events  Unique Events  Event Value  Avg. Value
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Links and Buttons   10            1              10           1
```

**Event Value** is calculated by `Total Events * value` where `value` is what you specified in the `_trackEvent` call.  Since you specified the value as 1, and there were 10 clicks, that makes for a total of 10 in the **Event Value** column.

**Avg. Value** is calculated by `Event Value / Total Events`. So in this scenario you have 10 events and a total event value of 10 since they are 1 value each, so the average value is 1.

Another example, let's say you have a regular link that you want to give a value of 1 per click, and you want to give you CTA links a higher value of 2 since they are worth more

```
// on your header language link
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links and Buttons', 'click', 'header links', 'language', 1]);

// on your CTA button
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links and Buttons', 'click', 'CTA', 'buy me!', 2]);
```

now let's say the header language link was clicked 10 times and the cta button was clicked 5 times (again, don't pay attention to **Unique Events** since this will vary depending on how many people click what). This is what you should expect to see:

```
Event Category      Total Events  Unique Events  Event Value  Avg. Value
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Links and Buttons   15            2              20           1.3
```

If you look at the event label as the dimension instead, you will see something like this:

```
Event Label      Total Events  Unique Events  Event Value  Avg. Value
------------------------------------------------------------------------
language         10            1              10           1
buy me!          5             1              10           2
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Can you provide some scenarios as to how someone can use this information? Why even give values at all etc? Or supply a link to read more bout it. I'm currently researching this. any help would be great!

Comment: @RoLYroLLs Basically, it's for weighting conversions. For example, signing up for a free account on your site is likely not worth as much as signing up for some premium/paid-for account.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs or, you can use it for stuff like.. time consumed on a video.

Comment: What option is there if we need string as values?  e.g.  "is this helpful?" : 'yes', 'no', or 'unknown'