# View Google Analytics event value

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using GA to track events for an Android App.

I track an event the usual way:

```
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
.setCategory(getString(categoryId))
.setAction(getString(actionId))
.setLabel(getString(labelId))
.setValue(longValue)
.build());
```

I can see the event in my reports but I can only see the total amount the event has occured. How can I see a brakedown of all the values I sent?

Comment: Are you checking in your Top Events reports? You should be able to find the Event Value, along with other metrics like Total Events, Avg Value, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't. That's not what the `value` argument is for. It's meant to be a metric (what you see on the right side of a report, the thing that gets added up). If you want to see those values individually (as a dimension), you're going to have to restructure what you are sending to include it in `category`, `action`, or `label`.

**Update:**

> But I DO want to use them as a metric. I want to create a custom
>   report with these values as metrices and with another custom dimension
>   I have created. I even asked about it in another question here:
>   stackoverflow.com/questions/30213318/…

Okay, I think you are misunderstanding what the difference between a dimension and a metric is.  A dimension tells you the "**what**",e.g. what event took place or what item was viewed.  A metric tells you the "**amount**", e.g. how many times the event took place or how much a video was consumed.

So, you are putting a specific number as the `value` for your events, which is a *metric*, but you are wanting to see the individual values you sent in. That's not what metrics do. If you want to see the individual numbers, this is why I said you need to restructure how you are sending those values in.  You need to instead send them in as the `category`, `action`, or `label`. *Then* you will be able to do what you want, for example:

> Let's say I'm creating a custom report or a dashboard. There I can
>   choose the dimension and metrices I want. Is there a way to somehow
>   choose a regular event as the metric? Let's say I got an event with
>   the label "label1" then I want a report with a dimension of date and a
>   metric "label1". Is that possible?

What you can then do is pick the date as a dimension, then choose the `category`, `action`, or `label` as a 2ndary dimension.  This will show you how many of one of those happened for a given date.  Or you can flip it, e.g. use `category` as primary dimension and then date as 2ndary and it will show you a breakdown by date.

But you can't put the `category`, `action`, or `label` in the *metrics* column.  That doesn't make sense.  As mentioned, metrics show you *how many/much* of the dimension there is.  The only exception is the `value` part of the event, which *is* a metric. But the metric column doesn't show you individual values. You can read more about how `value` shows up in reports, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22722302/184595).

`Value` is meant to give value to the dimension, e.g. establish order of importance.  For example, if you have a registration system in place and a visitor can register for a free or a premium account, from a conversion PoV, a premium registration is more valuable to you. So for e.g. you may give the free registration event a value of 1, but the premium reg a value of 2.

Or, it can be used in other ways, such as recording time consumed for a video, e.g. every 5 seconds a video is played, you pop an event with values e.g. Videos, Some Video Name, Time Consumed and a value of 5.  Then you can use that value metric to see things like total/avg time consumed for a given video.

**TL;DR:** A given event will let you send in 3 dimensions (`category`, `action`,`label`) and a metric (`value`) to give weight/amount to it. You are attempting to use `value` as if it were a dimension, when it's not. You are also attempting to use the dimensions as metrics, when they aren't.  I think what you *really* want is to break down one dimension (e.g. "Date") by another dimension (e.g `category`), and you also need to figure out how to record what you are currently putting into `value` as one of the dimension args.

**Update #2:**

> I was actually thinking of dimensions and metrices as an SQL table
>   where the dimensions are the primary keys and the metrices are the
>   regular column which will hold the value I will give it when I'm
>   sending the metric. So I wanted to see for example the dimension date
>   and a user id which can not repeat itself and in the metrices columns
>   just see every value I sent.. so it's actually wrong you say.

Ultimately everything is stored in a database, yes, but it's note as simple as being a straight, single table with entries, with simple queries. It's significantly more complex when it comes to analytics.

If I were to compare it to a SQL Table then dimensions (`category`,`action`,`label`) would be columns.  Then each row would represent a hit (where you trigger an event), and have values for them, e.g.

```
Category       Action       Label
Some Category  Some Action  Some Label
Some Category  Some Action  Some Label
Category 2     Some Action  Some Label
```

Now in reality, the db/table structure looks nothing like this. It's broken up into several tables etc.. but for sake of example this will do.

Now metrics on the other hand would be more like e.g. let's say you use `Category` as the dimension and just want to see a count of how many times the category values were recorded. So (again, super simplifying it), it'd look something like this:

```
select Category,count(Category) as `Total Events` from Table group by Category
```

So in the SQL results you'd have your rows showing your `Category` values and "Total Events" showing a sum of each one, e.g.

```
Category            Total Events
Some Category       2
Category 2          1
```

So that "Category" results column is a dimension, but that "Total Events" results column is a metric. So when you say e.g. "I want to use `Label` as a metric" well that doesn't make sense, because that's trying to take a value like "Some Category" and use it in an aggregated context, e.g. `"Some Category" + "Category 2" = ??` doesn't make sense!

So again, if you want to see the individual values you pass in `Value`, you will need to track it as a value in `Category`,`Action`, or `Label` (or, you can set a custom variable with your event), and then add it as a dimension in your report.

Comment: But I DO want to use them as a metric. I want to create a custom report with these values as metrices and with another custom dimension I have created. I even asked about it in another question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213318/use-googleanalytics-events-as-metrices

Comment: I was actually thinking of dimensions and metrices as an SQL table where the dimensions are the primary keys and the metrices are the regular column which will hold the value I will give it when I'm sending the metric. So I wanted to see for example the dimension date and a user id which can not repeat itself and in the metrices columns just see every value I sent.. so it's actually wrong you say.

Comment: @YonatanNir see **Update #2** !

Comment: I didn't notice the secondary dimension until now and it's exactly what I need and it also made me understand why the category/action/label are actually dimensions themselves. But what if I want to add another dimension and not just settle for the first 2? for example add a custom dimension of user ID and add a date as well. In the custom report I can't see the different categories/actions/labels..

Comment: @YonatanNir GA doesn't let you break things down more than 1 level deep, so you're mostly out of luck. What you *can* do to somewhat drill down more is make use of segments. But it's not quite the same thing and it really only helps a little as far as dong it for individual things.  For what you are wanting to do, you're moving into enterprise level tool territory, gonna have to pay for that sort of thing (e.g. implement Adobe Analytics or WebTrends)

Comment: But just something about what you said that I can't look at more than one level - I'm not sure if that's correct. You CAN choose several dimensions in a custom report and can create custom metrices for each type of event and then look at it as well and you can even add the value and avg. value as a metric.

Comment: @YonatanNir Yeah sorry, I should have been more clear.  Yes you can break down more than 1 level deep but on a given report GA won't show you more than 2 dimensions at a time.  So you can't see `Level 1 > Level 2 > Level 3 > etc..` all in one listing.   And yes, I mentioned in my post that `Value` *is* a metric type so you *can* add that one as a metric (and I also provided a link to another SO post I made that explains how `Event Value` and `Average Value` are calculated)

Comment: moved that comment to the end since it fits here more.
Great thank you. I have accepted the answer. You have also answered some of what I asked in another question I asked today but I would be glad if you could take a look at it. It's about user timings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324977/googleanalytics-hitbuilders-timingbuilder